# How to determine amount of augmented images in Keras?

Tags: generator, keras, image-preprocessing

I am working with Keras 2.0.0 and I'd like to train a deep model with a huge amount of parameters on a GPU. 
As my data are big, I have to use the `ImageDataGenerator`. To be honest, I want to abuse the `ImageDataGenerator` in that sense, that I don't want to perform any augmentations. I just want to put my training images into batches (and rescale them), so I can feed them to `model.fit_generator`.

I adapted the code from [here](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d) and did some small changes according to my data (i.e. changing binary classification to categorical. But this doesn't matter for this problem which should be discussed here).
I have 15000 train images and the only 'augmentation' I want to perform, is rescaling to scope [0,1] by `train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)`. 
After creating my 'train_generator' :

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle = True,
    seed = 1337,
    save_to_dir = save_data_dir)
```

I fit the model by using `model.fit_generator()`.

I set amount of epochs to: `epochs = 1`
And batch_size to: `batch_size = 60`

What I expect to see in the directory where my augmented (i.e. resized) images are stored: 15.000 rescaled images per epoch, i.e. with only one epoch: 15.000 rescaled images. But, mysteriously, there are 15.250 images.

Is there a reason for this amount of images? 
Do I have the power to control the amount of augmented images?

Similar problems:

[Model fit_generator not pulling data samples as expected](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3461) (respectively at stackoverflow: [Keras - How are batches and epochs used in fit_generator()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936016/keras-how-are-batches-and-epochs-used-in-fit-generator))

[A concrete example for using data generator for large datasets such as ImageNet](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1627)

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it does not answer my question. I understand what ImageDataGenerator does and how it works. But I cannot understand why it behaves like stated in my initial post...