# Keras different results between predict and predict_generator

Tags: keras, predict

I am currently using Keras for satellite image classification and i have troubles getting the right predictions using predict and predict_generator.

Below my code

```
import os
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd
from keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD
from tools import load_val_datas, load_test_datas, make_predictions, make_submissions
from keras_tools import save_model, load_model

from callbacks import CustomCallbacks
from data_generator import ImageDataGenerator
from model import base_cnn

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

TRAIN_SIZE, VAL_SIZE, TEST_SIZE, TEST_SIZE_ADD = 30000, 10479, 40669, 20522
IMAGE_FIRST_DIM, N_COLORS = 32, 3
IMAGE_SIZE = IMAGE_FIRST_DIM * IMAGE_FIRST_DIM * N_COLORS
LABEL_SIZE = 17
DROPOUT = 0.25
BATCH_SIZE = 96
N_EPOCHS = 2
CHECKPOINTS_FOLDER = "checkpoints/"
MODEL_JSON = "epoch-10.json"
MODEL_H5 = "epoch-10.h5"
TO_LOAD = False

df_train_labels = pd.read_csv("datas/train_labels.csv")
label_dict = df_train_labels.set_index("image_name").T.to_dict("list")

val_x, val_y = load_val_datas(VAL_SIZE, IMAGE_FIRST_DIM, N_COLORS, LABEL_SIZE)

if TO_LOAD:
    model, is_loaded = load_model(CHECKPOINTS_FOLDER + MODEL_JSON, CHECKPOINTS_FOLDER + MODEL_H5)
else:
    model = base_cnn(IMAGE_FIRST_DIM, N_COLORS)

adam = Adam(lr=0.01)
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9, decay=0.0005)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)

my_callbacks = CustomCallbacks()
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory("datas/train", target_size=(IMAGE_FIRST_DIM, IMAGE_FIRST_DIM),
                                              batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                              class_mode="multilabel", multilabel_classes=label_dict)

val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory("datas/validation", target_size=(IMAGE_FIRST_DIM, IMAGE_FIRST_DIM),
                                              batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=False,
                                              class_mode="multilabel", multilabel_classes=label_dict)

model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=TRAIN_SIZE/BATCH_SIZE, epochs=N_EPOCHS,
                    verbose=2)
save_model(model, MODEL_JSON, MODEL_H5)

from time import time
st = time()
p_valid = model.predict_generator(val_generator, steps=VAL_SIZE/BATCH_SIZE, pickle_safe=True)
print("time: ", time() - st)
print(p_valid)
from sklearn.metrics import fbeta_score
print(fbeta_score(val_y, np.array(p_valid) > 0.2, beta=2, average='samples'))

st = time()
p_valid1 = model.predict(val_x)
print("time: ", time() - st)
print(type(p_valid1))
print(fbeta_score(val_y, np.array(p_valid1) > 0.2, beta=2, average='samples'))
```

i am using a different version of ImageDataGenerator that can handle multilabel (I already checked the implementation and the datas look correctly loaded in batch)

The troubles comes from the predict and predict_generator part where i get different results from both. I double checked with a model trained without generator and the output from predict is correct (and very different from the output from predict_generator). Datas feeded in predict are constructed the same way the generator will do (also checked that).

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
validation images loaded in 0.01 seconds
validation labels loaded in 0.00 seconds


Found 30000 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 10479 images belonging to 1 classes.
Epoch 1/2
63s - loss: 0.2762
Epoch 2/2
66s - loss: 0.2288
time:  22.098024606704712
beta_score: 0.667686382255
time:  3.3181281089782715
beta_score: 0.740394519272
```

Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: It might be caused by shuffling. Try to leave your network for more epochs.

Comment: I put shuffle=False for the validation generator. The training is correct. And i also did the test for 5 and 10 epochs results are the same. I am gonna try with 1 image in the val_x to have more visibility

Comment: Might be linked to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938176/why-differ-metrics-calculated-by-model-evaluate-from-tracked-metrics-during-tr ?

Comment: Ok i am just an idiot... ImageDataGenerator is getting the filenames in a "weird order" which is not the same as i am doing manually ... it looks fine after all

Answer (score 0):

I think this comment on a similar issue on GitHub might help someone
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3477#issuecomment-360022086

The output from predict() and predict_generator() are actually identical, but they look different because they are labelled differently. You are providing the labels to predict(), and predict_generator() is inferring the labels (because it's using flow_from_directory() instead of flow()) from the directory structure of training data.